# Ansible - How can I fail tasks but continue the playbook?

Tags: ansible

Below is a part of a script for illustration.
Basically it's testing for open ports between different servers and it works ok, but I cannot find a way to make the output error out if there are failures.

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ target_host }}"
  gather_facts: true
  become: yes
  become_method: runas
  become_user: System
  tasks:
   
    - set_fact:
        mcs: '{{ env_type }}_mcs'
        ism: '{{ env_type }}_ism'
        ire: '{{ env_type }}_ire'
        afs: '{{ env_type }}_afs'
      delegate_to: "{{ target_host }}"
      with_items: "{{ play_hosts }}"
      run_once: yes

- hosts: '{{ env_type }}_ism'
  gather_facts: false
  become_method: runas
  become_user: System
  tasks:
    - name: Test ports from ISM
      block:
        - name: Test ISM to IRE 2861
          ansible.windows.win_wait_for:
            host: "{{ item }}"
            port: 2861
            timeout: 3
          ignore_errors: yes
          loop: "{{ groups[ire] }}"
      rescue:
        - debug:
            msg: "Failure occurred "
            
- hosts: '{{ env_type }}_ire'
  gather_facts: false
  become_method: runas
  become_user: System
  tasks:
    - name: Test IRE to IFS 445
      ansible.windows.win_wait_for:
        host: "{{ item }}"
        port: 445
        timeout: 3
      ignore_errors: yes
      loop: "{{ groups[afs] }}"
```

I want the whole script to finish. I don't want it to fail and stop in the middle. But if I'm ignoring errors - it'll be all green with a couple of skipped. If I add the block  and set ignore_errors to false and fail in the block it will stop the execution. And I cannot encapsulate all the tasks in the block because they run on different hosts.

I'm not really sure if there's anything I can do here to make the tasks fail but continue till the end.

Comment: so its about red or green?

Comment: Yes, you can say so. I just need that the people who will be running it can easily see the task that fails in the summary instead of looking through the whole output. at every task individually.

Answer (score 1):

> *if there's anything I can do here to make the tasks fail but continue till the end.*

Instead of [ignoring failed commands](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#ignoring-failed-commands) at all it is recommended to [define failure](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-failure) like

```yaml
failed_when: "CONDITION is 'met'"
```

You may also have a look into [`assert` module – Asserts given expressions are true](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html).